# How to create RSACng from a public key in GenericPublicBlob format?

Tags: c#, cng

I am using `System.Security.Cryptography.Cng` (4.7.0).

I have exported a public key from a `CngKey` object using

```
byte[] publicKey = cngKey.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPublicBlob);
```

How can I use this at a later time to create an `RSACng` object for public-key encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CngKey` can be recreated from the blob like this:

```
using CngKey key = CngKey.Import(blob, CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPublicBlob);
```

And then we can create an `RSACng` for e.g. encrypting data:

```
using RSACng rsaCng = new RSACng(key);
```